# QGIS switch layer on and off

Tags: qgis, mac

I have made an update from a previous version of qgis, after that I could not switch a layer on and off. After that I deleted everything, incl. all folders in the path inside ./qgis2/ and reinstalled everything. nothing helped. how can I fix this strange bug?

screenshot from Layers Panel:
[image: screenshot from Layers Panel]

My System:
QGIS 2.18.9
OSX 10.11.6

Comment: yes, I tried this and it works fine.

Comment: So might this be a solution for your problem or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by changing the system setting for the mouse and the ink back to default. everything is fine now :-)

[image]

[image]